# Enable nice urls / permalinks in CentOS + Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

We've got a fresh CentOS box and we need to enable nice urls / permalinks. We're running Apache with mod_rewrite installed but I'm aware I need edit a few config files to get the basics up and running.

What are the steps and files that need to be changed in order to get it up and running?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to be a lot more specific than that. What are you trying to do? Do you have a webserver already installed? What are you serving?

Comment: Sorry your right, I will clarify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with David Pashley - this is a somewhat vague question.

However I'm going to take a guess from looking at the question tags that you're using Apache as your webserver. In which case you will want to explore Mod_Rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html and modify either your Httpd.conf or .htaccess files to manipulate url rewrites.

If you're using Lighttpd you would want to look at http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRewrite

There are still a lot of 'ifs' in your question you might want to elaborate on. Some web frameworks will handle this for you (Rails, Django, CakePHP, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone else is looking for the answer simply edit

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Find the line

Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Restart, Win